# Need to expose internal Sharepoint 2010 Document Library to External website

Tags: document-library, intranet, public-website, internet

We have a Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise portal made for internal employees. Now we need to make the documents library available to an internet website so that outside users can access those documents as well.

We want to maintain the documents inside the Sharepoint rather than copy them to the external website.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Definitely possible as long as you are covered on licensing aspects. You can set the appropriate permissions on your internal web and configure your Alternate Access Mapping correctly and have the site accessible from outside

or

- Alternatively you can build a simple asp.net control that exposes the document library via some custom work done by you. Mind you it will be your own interface.This will interact with SharePoint Web Services or you can develop your own ones as well.