# Embedding SharePoint in a website

Tags: integration, iframe

I have a web app and I would like to attach some files in SharePoint and manage it as resources in my external web application. Ie. SharePoint files mashed up in my web app.

I can generate URLs and would like to use this to filter the files for a certain context. My question is specifically about:

- Can I pass some key / user in the URL to make logins transparent?
- Can Sharepoint be embedded in an IFrame like this in a mashup style. (Do
  not want navigation, menus etc... it should be "transparent")
- Can I prompt the user to login (user+password form) and then redirect to the url?

I do not know SharePoint so any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Here is some additional info with two specific example use cases:

- One of the applications can be Oracle CRM On Demand (OCOD) using [Client Side Extensions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22393_01/books/OnDemOLH/index.htm?toc.htm?uploadclientextensions.html).
- As for the other one, I would like to make **REST API** calls and thus using traditional SOAP web services is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Thus, if I need to enhance my client web app I'm a bit constraint using OCOD, but I'm free to perhaps add some AJAX and/or Javascript in the mix.

Any ideas or thoughts would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

A similar question: [Need to expose internal Sharepoint 2010 Document Library to External website](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25472/need-to-expose-internal-sharepoint-2010-document-library-to-external-website)

IMHO using web service to get documents from SharePoint is right way of doing it. You can handle all login/authentication on your website and you can develop custom control to display sharepoint documents. Using iframe is quick and dirty way of doing it.

Some (I hope) helpfull links:

- [Lists Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [SharePoint List Web Service GetListItems](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2009/12/sharepoint-list-web-service.html)
- [WSS Integration with .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87867/WSS-Integration-with-NET)

Comment: I was just typing nearly this same message when I got the notice a new answer had been added! ;-) I would only add don't forget the Client Object Model if your other application is .NET based and you are using SharePoint 2010.